# Issue with the power bi gateway and data source that cant refresh the data

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to refresh the power bi report from power bi service by changing the gate way. i was hitting the below error. The source file is Access DB file.

> Cannot connect to the mashup data source. See error details for more information.
>   Please try again later or contact support. If you contact support, please provide these details.
>
> Underlying error code-2147467259 Table: tbl_ManagerPOC.
>   Underlying error messageUnspecified error
>   DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingHResult-2147467259
>   Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.ReasonDataFormat.Error
>   Cluster URIWABI-US-NORTH-CENTRAL-redirect.analysis.windows.net
>   Activity ID643f0e00-2c0a-4f45-8fb4-2043dc59d3eb
>   Request IDf615a46a-beac-4036-8d62-d6e56b1add08
>   Time2018-12-20 16:42:30Z

Comment: Have you updated the DS credentials? and looked that the file is still available in the location mentioned in the DS in PowerBI settings?